# How can i remove the Boot flag from a non EXT drive?

Tags: 11.10

I've accidentally set an NTFS drive with a boot flag during a recent re-installation of Xubuntu 11.10, How can i undo that without deleting the partition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Disk Utility` select the partition, click on Edit partition and untick the Bootable box

[image: gnome-disk-utility]

If you don't have that installed, then simply do `sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility`

Comment: :) simple stuff sometimes eludes me too.